# How should the multiplication symbol be written in the mathematical formula of a research paper? *? or x?

Tags: mathematics

How should the multiplication symbol be written in the mathematical formula of a research paper?  *? or x?

The field is computer science and I am multiplying integers.

Comment: There is no general rule - it depends on the specific context of your paper and the conventions in your subsubsubfield.  Generally you'll be fine with whatever you find least confusing to the reader.

Comment: The only context in which the asterisk would be appropriate is in samples of code in a programming language in twhich it represents the numerical operation. For the mathematical operation itself (not the computational approximation thereto), asterisk would never be used. As others have pointed out, you could use × or · nothing. The usage of the asterisk for multiplication derives from its presence on typical keyboards (and the absence of any more suitable character).

Comment: In code use * or whatever the language demands, otherwise for humans an appropriate mathematical symbol for multiplication as in the answer of @Arno. Also, though you didn't ask, don't write 'the _p_ value was less than 1e-2'; standard scientific notation instead.

Answer (score 7):

What you write is $\times$, which LaTeX then renders as the proper multiplication symbol. This looks similar to the letter x, but is readily distinguishable from it.

Comment: Or $\cdot$. Or (most often) nothing. Depends on the context.

Comment: @AdamPřenosil Well, agreed, the vast majority of multiplications in my papers are denoted by the absence of any symbol. And if I do need one, I am indeed quite likely to pick $\cdot$ over $\times$ (which instead I predominately use for the cartesian product). But $\times$ is THE multiplication symbol.

Answer (score 3):

I thought it might be useful to give an edge-case answer: first, sure, if it's "multiplication" of standard algebraic things (numbers, matrices, ...) simply *juxtaposition*, or a "cdot", or "times" in TeX. Still, if it's composition of operators of some sort, a TeX "circ" (all these things with leading backslash, of course) might be good.

Even further, in C++ and others, it is possible to "overload" an operator. Sure, often, this overloading merely amounts to extending multiplication of integers to multiplication of Gaussian integers, etc.  But not always. In the more extreme cases, where your operation is really an overloading of a/the more elementary idea of multiplication, definitely use a little-bit-special symbol to alert the reader that it's "not just the usual".

But, for "plain" multiplication, as opposed to literal computer code (or maybe pseudo-code), do not use an asterisk. :)

Answer (score 2):

In Microsoft Word, type 00d7 and then Alt-X. This gives the multiplication symbol.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_sign

However, it is probably better to put nothing. See comments.